# How to willingly not award a bounty?

Tags: support, bounty

I have started a bounty on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594519/how-do-i-get-localized-date-pattern-string). The question received some more answers, but actually none of those is answering the specific problem I wanted to be addressed with the bounty. So I would like to dismiss the bounty. How can I do that or isn't that possible at all?

In this specific case, not awarding the bounty by me would automatically award it to an answer, that was not intended by my bounty.

Comment: Related: [Explicit “do not award bounty” button](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166172/explicit-do-not-award-bounty-button) - Currently there is no such feature.

Comment: should be a META.SE post and not SO

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's no way to stop a bounty from being automatically awarded if an answer meets the criteria for it to happen.

It sucks, but that's the way it is.

[As indicated by @animuson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260141/how-to-willingly-not-award-a-bounty#comment40552_260141), there's a feature request to make this possible: [Explicit "do not award bounty" button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166172/explicit-do-not-award-bounty-button)

Comment: It doesn't suck.  Bounties are not refundable in order to prevent gaming.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Nobody says anything about refunding the bounty. It's about forfeiting the bounty altogether. This doesn't help with gaming at all.

Comment: @Antony No, but then you can have situations where help vampires withhold bounty until their *newly discovered* bug is fixed. Or, people just doing it out of spite, which I think would damage the bounty system (no one would trust it, really).

Comment: Fine, don’t refund bounties. That solves the gaming/vampires/spite issues. Fine. But it is a deeply flawed solution that auto-awards bounties to answers that we thought were so bad that we felt compelled to offer a bounty in the first place.

Answer (score 20):

A bounty incites users to invest time into the question. Forfeiting it is essentially [bait-and-switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bait-and-switch):

- The benefactor would lose the reputation anyway, so this makes no difference to them.
- On the other hand, a contestant not receiving anything despite investing time and effort and producing a good-enough result (as upvotes signify) would justfully feel cheated.

If the answer is good enough for the peers, but still not quite good enough for the benefactor, a contestant already gets a penalty by only receiving half of the bounty.

Just as an additional argument: [the official answer to "Explicit "do not award bounty" button"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166172/explicit-do-not-award-bounty-button/265812#265812) states that they *already had* this feature long ago, and it *proved to be bad.*

Comment: @user626528 if one posted an answer, they already invested time to write it. So I don't see how's that relevant.

Comment: not really. Brainless answers don't deserve a reward as the time investment was nearly non-existent.

Comment: @user626528 "brainless answers" won't get the upvotes to qualify for automatic-half-of-bounty. So I already addressed this.

Comment: they do. I've seen quite a few brainless answers that were upvoted.

Comment: @user626528 if they got upvoted enough times, they may not be so brainless, after all. If you think the upvotes are fraudulent, you should report the post to the mods. If you think that users in general are too incompetent to trust them with upvotes, that's another matter entirely and you should open another question about it.

Comment: some of them definitely are brainless. Why were they upvoted - well, you should know better.

Comment: @user626528 If you think that stuff gets upvoted that shouldn't, you should open another topic if you wish to do something about it. That's no reason to allow withholding a bounty because the problem is not in the bounty system but in the voting system.