# Bounty about to be auto-awarded to an existing answer?

Tags: discussion, bounty

This is similar but not *exactly* the same as [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260141/how-to-willingly-not-award-a-bounty)

I have a question with a single answer which, although helpful, has not resolved my issue. I put a 5 day, 300 point bounty on it to get more attention and hopefully a correct answer. It failed.

The 5 days are up, and the single non-resolving answer stands to win it, even though it predates my bounty by a few weeks.

If I put another bounty on this question, is it just going to end up going to the same answer? How do I avoid giving that answer all future bounties?

Answer (score 3):

Bounties are only auto-awarded to answers that were posted in the bounty period. Answers that were posted before you added the bounty to the question do not qualify.

Quoting from [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work):

> ### What is automatic awarding?
>
> [...]
>
> The criteria for an answer to be eligible are:
>
> - **The answer must have been given after the bounty was started**
>
> [...]
>
> If neither of these conditions apply, the bounty is not awarded to any answer, and is not refunded to the bounty starter.

Comment: ok, good to know. There's a greyed out "300" badge under the answer, I just assumed that's where it would go

Comment: @roryok: you can always *manually* award the bounty to that answer, it just won't get any award *automatically*. Even if you marked it as accepted.