# Bounty has been awarded against the stated rules

Tags: support, bounty

In **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34871518/how-to-apply-title-case-in-input-box-through-css/34872475#34872475)** OP started bounty of 50. I have given the answer with highest score and accepted answer. But OP didn't award bounty to an one, i think because OP want any better answer which works perfect.

But, after the bounty period end as per written **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)**   "**bounty owner liked the answer they accepted and award it the full bounty amount at the time of bounty expiration**".

[image]

As per above comments bounty will be awarded to accepted answer and/Or highest  voted answer. Here both are [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34871518/how-to-apply-title-case-in-input-box-through-css/34872475#34872475).

Then how half bounty is awarded to another answer. And half to no one?

Here bounty system works wrong? 
Or i am wrong anywhere?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You were not awarded the bounty because you placed the answer *before* the bounty was started.

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), **the highest voted answer created after the bounty started** with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount. If two or more eligible answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the oldest answer is chosen. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, no bounty is awarded to anyone.

The answer that received the half bounty award was placed after the bounty was created and received a score exceeding the minimum requirement of 2.

Comment: "...received more than 2 upvotes." - Not quite. It needs a positive score of at least 2. It's possible to get 2 or more upvotes, and still have an insufficient score due to downvotes.

Comment: Looks very strange indeed. Why should the time when the answer was composed matter? Is there a rationale mentioned somewhere?

Comment: Sorry to keep nitpicking, but it's "a minimum score of 2".

Comment: @MikeM., no problem with the picking. In this case though, I wanted to make it clear that the other answer met the criteria, not just reached the minimum.

Comment: This is some what  weird things. I didn't notice that. Actually i have deleted answer first after that found some solution and undelete after bounty started. But, this id strange rule of bounty.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev, There probably is a discussion on either MSO or MSE somewhere about the rationale. I can't find it right now. But, this is how it's worked since bounties were [introduced](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/reputation-bounty-for-unanswered-questions/).

Comment: Right, but the last part of your answer is saying the minimum is 3.

Comment: Worked like this since the beginning, eh? Then this warrants a separate discussion (probably @MSE). You may refer to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260141/how-to-willingly-not-award-a-bounty/311437#311437 for explanation on how the votes already decide "good enough" answers.