# Should I not award the bounty if I think that my own answer is the best?

Tags: discussion, bounty, etiquette, self-answer

So I put a bounty on [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35128339/error-no-value-given-for-one-or-more-required-parameters-excel-sql-query) that didn't get much attention, because I wanted to find a resolution for it.

It gained one answer that didn't work (with a bit more work on the answer it *could* have, but it was also using a route I didn't want to go down).

After some research and trial-and-error, I came up with my own solution which worked for me. I accepted my own answer because, well, it works, and then added some more detail to make it more useful.

However, obviously I can't award a bounty to myself, and the other answer didn't work for me.

Is it the best practice to just let the bounty expire and not award it to anyone?

Comment: Related: [How to willingly not award a bounty?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260141/2675154)

Comment: Why would you even imagine you might need to award the bounty to an answer that didn't work for you?

Comment: @torazaburo because it auto awards anyway

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can let the bounty expire if you don't feel that the other answer adequately solved your problem or helped you figure out your solution. Don't feel like you have to pay out the bounty or "make it worthwhile" — it's perfectly normal for bounties to go unawarded in this sort of scenario.